# Убрать слеш в конце url?

Tags: apache, nginx, php-fpm

Есть сервер Apache+NGINX+PHP.
1.Структура сайта сайт_1/сайт_2/
2.URL сата site.ru/site2/

Как убрать слеш в конце?
Проблема вся в том что сейчас в F12 показывает 301 редирект с site.ru/site2 на site.ru/site2/

Нигде не могу найти этот редирект ,блокировал .htaccess ,пробовал добавить в nginx правило 
location = /site/ { return 301 $scheme://$host/site; }
Что приводило к циклу и ошибке.
Пробовал добавить в apache 
DirectorySlash off
SetHandler script-handler
Что приводит к 404 по адресу site.ru/site2

Comment: Может быть, что где-то в кишках фреймворка редирект стоит

Comment: Да вот уж тоже думаю, но раскопать сложно там что ..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
location /site2 {
                root /var/www/html/;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri /site2/index.html;
```